# Trouble running emulator in android studio

Tags: android-emulator

I am unable to run the emulator in android studio. I received a "Your cpu does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)" message. Someone told me to try and do what this link states "http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/" which led me to a video and I tried following those directions but was unable to because  first, there was no HyperV feature in the Windows features section. Second,  there was no UEFI Firmware settings icon when I went to advanced settings in set up. How can I proceed from here to enable the VT-x in order for me to be able to use the emulator in Android studios? Thank you so much!!

Comment: if your cpu does not support it, you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay your cpu does not support is not the same as cannot use emulator you just have to use one that runs x86 images which is in fact GenyMotion...

https://www.genymotion.com/

sign up for free account and when you download you want the full install package with virtualbox included.

and it does support instantrun just like the google android emulators do

You will also find the android studio genymotion plugin at the same site to download and use with android studiio

Comment: thank you so much for that!! I signed up for that & was trying to figure out which type to sign up for (when I signed in they had a "business" option & then an option to contact them) so I sent them an email asking which one to sign up for & how. I'm anxious to get that taken care of so i can finsh this nanodegree & find employment in the tech field. Anyway, thank you so much again for your time & assistance!!!